# How to send CTRL-Alt-F[1-9] to guests in the VMWare ESXI Web Client?

Tags: vmware, esxi

How to send CTRL-Alt-F[1-9] to clients in the VMWare ESXI Web Client? I need this to access the other virtual consoles in the guest.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/852267/226427), which works for me:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
>
> That's all you'll need.

Answer (score -1):

Read this I hope help you
https://websistent.com/vmware-ctrl-alt-function-key/
in short it try to using combination by pres ctrl+alt+space and then release space and press a F key.

Comment: Doesn't work. It just switches my host system to a TTY. Which makes sense, because if you released Space key, why would it be still counted by your OS? When you play games and hold Shift and key `a` and then release `a` and press key `b` — wouldn't you expect the game to react same as if you just pressed Shift + `b`? So of course pressing F3 after Space is released is counted the same as just `Ctrl + Alt + F3`.